# Oven Door allows too much heat to escape?

Tags: oven

I recently bought a used, Amana gas range.  It works, for the most part, quite well.
The problem is that the oven door is not making a proper seal with the range body, which allows too much heat to escape from the top, where the door meets the body.  Over time, I expect that the amount of heat released will damage the electronic control panel.

Do any of you experts have a suggested course of action to take?
I figure I could:

- replace the hinges (they feel a little light)
- tighten the hinges (how?)
- replace the oven door gasket with a slightly thicker one

Comments and solutions appreciated.

[image: Range Door Hinge Closeup]

Comment: Where does it feel like the heat is escaping from?

Comment: Good question.  I should have describe it better.  It's escaping from the top, where the door meets the body.  I believe this model is a bit notorious for this.  When I apply light pressure on the door to tighten the seal against the body, I can no longer feel the waves of heat escaping.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution. I have the same issue on my Amana ACS3350AS. Part of it was that the door had been bent right above the hinges due to maybe letting the door drop and or cleaning it when fully open. I fixed this by opening the door and adding some angle Al reinforcement. It still lets some heat out, I might try replacing hinges next.

Comment: My dad cuts a wine cork to just the right thickness so that it jams between the side of the oven door and the outer housing of the oven; all off which are supposed to be low heat areas. That lets him shut the door extra tight, and eliminates escapage from around the top of the door. It's kludgery, but he's an engineer who knows what he's doing, and it works.

Answer (score 3):

It varies by model number but generally there's a spring that attaches to the door hinge. If the hinge (or other part that links to the spring) breaks then there isn't enough tension to keep the door closed.

I had the same problem. In my case the roller broke which caused the hinge to not operate properly.

Look up your model number and look at the parts diagram to get a better sense of how your oven is set up.

If you remove the door (usually lifts straight up) you can see everything better and operate the hinges manually to see which one has a problem.